# achieve "friends data model" with postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-modeling

I need some guidance on how to setup what im trying to achieve. I'm creating a database in postgres and need help with how i should setup my data model.

I'm working on a personal app and basically i have tables for users, transactions, and groups.

users has columns `(id, email)` transactions has columns `(id, amount, user_id, ...)`

so basically the gist is individual users have their own transactions. The tricky part for me is setting up the groups portion

Groups can consist of 2 users or more, and what i want to achieve is when 2 or more users become a group, i want all users to be able to get the TOTAL AMOUNT from the other users transactions.

I thought handling the groups table as a typical "friends data model" with `user_id_one` and `user_id_two` with the proper uniqueness and constraints would help, but im stuck.

So what I need help with is,

How should the group's table look like? (Or is there another approach I can take, add another table? what kind of relation?)

what the query should look like that would get both users transactions? (I could just add up all the amounts on the server if it can't be done through the query)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

So like I understand you should create some kind of linking table
Example:

```
|  [Users]  |             |[UserGroups]|             |  [Groups]  |
|user_id    |             |id          |             |group_id    |
|email      | ∞         1 |user_id     | 1         ∞ |other_data  |
|other data | ----------> |group_id    | <---------- |            |
```

Then for exmaple you can write the query to fetch all transactions for given group:

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions t JOIN UserGroups ug ON t.user_id = ug.user_id WHERE ug.group_id= ?;
```

I don't know exactly what queries you want but it's only example.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. with the solution you proposed, im guessing I will have to store the `group_id` in with the [Users] table, right? in order to complete the WHERE clause

Comment: No that is not necessary. What is missing from the diagram is the Transaction table which of necessity contains user_id as a FK to User, the UserGroups table also contains user_id as a FK to User. Now it you do not need/want any other attributes from User just join Transactions to UserGroups directly, as the query by @Serkus does. The only thing need is to supply the group_id to the query. No table/columns changes are needed. If you still need help getting Group and/or User columns then post that as a new question.